# How to automate generating PDF outputs of Tableau worksheets and dashboards in a specific sequence using Python and the Tableau JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, python, automation, tableau-api

I have a .twbx template file containing multiple worksheets and dashboards in a specific sequence. I would like to automate the process of applying filters, generating a combined pdf  output containing each sheet and dashboard image as in tableau, in the same sequence as the .twbx file using Python and the Tableau JavaScript API/Tableau REST API.

**Here are the key requirements:**

1. Apply filters to each sheet and dashboard programmatically before generating PDF outputs.
2. Preserve the original sequence of the worksheets and dashboards from the .twbx file in the generated PDF outputs.
3. Automate the process to generate a large number of pdfs approximately 2500 or more).

Ideally, accomplish this using Python and the Tableau JavaScript API.
I have explored the Tableau JavaScript API and found it suitable for interacting with Tableau Server and performing individual tasks. However, I'm unsure how to iterate through each sheet and dashboard in the desired sequence, apply filters, generate PDF outputs, and save them in the correct order using Python.

Can anyone provide guidance or example code snippets on how to achieve this automation?

Additionally, if there are alternative approaches or libraries that can help accomplish this task, I'm open to suggestions.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Wanted a method that can utilise JavaScript to achieve this automation.